# how to find the start with value of a db sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I was trying to find a way to know the start with value of given sequence in oracle sql. 
Is there a way to do that?

Further, I wanted to list that with the below for the current max value as

```
select object_name.NEXTVAL 
from DUAL 
where object_name IN 
(select object_name from all_objects where object_type like 'SEQUENCE')
```

but this results into syntax error.

Comment: First of all `DUAL` doesn't have `object_name` column. Are you trying to find next val of _all_ sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sequence_name,
       LAST_NUMBER as NEXT_VAL,
       MIN_VALUE as START_WITH
from dba_sequences 
where sequence_name ='S';
```

**P.S.** 
By the time of the result, chances are likely that the sequence could have been increment by another process

`LAST_NUMBER` will not be accurate if your sequence is defined with a CACHE > 1 ! (sequences would be generated in advance and cached for performance) So only `NEXT_VAL` can be used to find it. But calling `NEXT_VAL` even for printing purpose would increment it.

`MIN_VALUE` will be equal to `START_WITH` only if `START_WITH` is not specified while creation! And There's ***NO*** way to find it, except for checking the `DDL`.

Query to get the DDL of Sequence:

```
dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE', 'SEQ_NAME')
```

Credits to [Nicholas Krasnov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997660/nicholas-krasnov)

Comment: If OP by the `start with` meant the value that has been provided for the start with clause upon sequence creation, then there is no guarantee that `min_value` equals to `start with` value, it might be equal if the same value has been specified for the `start with` and `minvalue` clauses, say, `1`. `Last_number` (not `last_number + increment_by`) might indicate the value that will be returned next ONLY if a sequence has been created with `nocache` clause, otherwise this is not the next value to be returned by the sequence

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov yes, I was wrong. I edited, as much as I can. You could post your information as an answer and I would delete mine.!

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov may be STARTS with was implemented by incrementing the sequence automatically till the specified value

Comment: I'm sorry @OracleUser. Seems like I was wrong, and even `dbms_ddl` cannot be relied on. If `nocache` clause has not been included, the `cache` value will be taken into consideration anyway - `start with` [changes when extracting sequence's ddl](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cf0e2/4). Honestly, did not expect that.

Comment: yup.. Interesting.. it too changes as per cached count.. So start value in DDL literally means when it want to start its new generation(after cached values).. isn't it?

Comment: There was a typo in my previous comment, of course it's `dbms_metadata` not `dbms_ddl`. `dbms_metadata` uses data dictionary views to construct DDLs, so naturally the result cannot be different, of course. And it means that the initially specified `start with` value cannot be accurately determined when a sequence has been created without `nocache` clause.